# Какие есть способы послать нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре? c++/cli

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++-cli

Какие существуют способы программного управления клавиатурой, при помощи языка C++/CLI?
Пишу небольшую программку по событию происходит нажатие кнопки клавиатуры. Знаю пока один способ, не очень приятный - это использование WinApi, которое в сочетании с C++/CLI выносит мне мозг. Может есть способ попроще?

Comment: Вам надо нажимать кнопку в другом приложении? На какой технологии это приложение сделано? PS: не использйте C++/CLI. PPS: посмотрите AutoIt/AutoHotKey.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Да, нужно нажать кнопку в другом приложении. Приложение, которое принимает нажатие клавиши любой просмотрщик pdf или просмотрщик презентаций PowerPoint. AutoIt/AutoHotKey наверное не подойдет, уже написана часть программы(fronend для приема данных с микроконтроллера + backend для микроконтроллера)

Comment: нашел простой способ использования winapi для c++/cli может кому пригодится [ссылка](https://www.oipapio.com/question-1728964)

Comment: или [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021175/sendinput-keyboard-letters-c-c) работает как карма